# Ionic2 tabs - Load different page/component based on data from service

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a app that has 4 tabs, the first one being "home" and it has a home.html, home.ts etc. I also have another page called "details", depending on a service call if a certain field is null then i show content of home.html, if that field is not null then i show the content of details.html and the corresponding details.ts

how/where do i put my switch statement to load the different page?

```
export class TabsPage {
// this tells the tabs component which Pages
// should be each tab's root Page
tab1Root: any = HomePage;
tab2Root: any = PlacePage;
tab3Root: any = EventsPage;
tab4Root: any = SettingsPage;
```

constructor() {

}

Would i be doing this in the constructor of the tab (call the service and determine assign the appropriate page here?

EDIT:
I can do this

```
export class TabsPage {
// this tells the tabs component which Pages
// should be each tab's root Page
tab1Root: any
tab2Root: any = MasjidsPage;
tab3Root: any = EventsPage;
tab4Root: any = SettingsPage;

constructor() {
//switch here  
this.tab1Root = PlaceDetailsPage;
}
}
```

but placedetailspage requires i have a param in navParams so before i assign it, i somehow need to give it a navParam

Comment: [rootParams] is what you need on the iontab